# Problems with RegEx with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

```
else if( (m = url.match(/^(https?:\/\/ww[\d]+\.sinaimg\.cn\/)([^\/]+)(\/.+)$/i)) ) {
    if(m[2] != "large") {
        document.location = m[1] + "large" + m[3];
    }
}
```

So the above is a working piece of Javascript... And I am trying to make a regex  of another URL that fits into the code... But I couldn't seemd to quite get how it works...

What is `m[1]` and `m[3]` BTW?

This is the URL I intend to change about:

> a.up.w.com/i/EF8W-P67s6dqRPIj7cLlMQ!/fw/300/format/jpg/quality/90

How can I make a Regex that replaces 300 to 3000, jpg to png (or not) and 90 to 100?
I made this one but nothing seemed to work...

```
else if( (m = url.match(/^(https?:\/\/a\+\.up\.w\.com\/i\/)([^\/]+)(\/fw\/)([^\/]+)(\/format\/)([^\/+])(\/quality\/+)([^\/]+)$/i)) ) {
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/^(https?://ww[\d]+.sinaimg.cn/)([^/]+)(/.+)$/i

To read regular expressions most people need some automated tool as a helper.
I created your regex with an example: https://regex101.com/r/mP5zI9/3

Example caught link: https://ww1.sinaimg.cn/aaa/bbb.jpg
1.  `https://ww1.sinaimg.cn/`
2.  `aaa`
3.  `/bbb.jpg`

the m array contains the different parts of the match.

For full javascript details see: [MDN documentation for String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: I tried using it before, and now my RegEx seems fine: (https?:\/\/a+\.up+\.w+\.com\/i\/+)([^\/]+)(\/fw\/+)([^\/]+)(\/format\/+)([^\/+]+)(\/quality\/+)([^\/]+)

Comment: else if( (m = url.match(/^(https?:\/\/a+\.up+\.w+\.com\/i\/+)([^\/]+)(\/fw\/+)([^\/]+)(\/format\/+)([^\/+]+)(\/quality\/+)([^\/]+)$/i)) ) {
        if(m[4] != "3000" || m[8] !=100) {
            document.location = m[1] + m[2] + m[3] + "3000" + m[5] + m[6] + m[7] + "100";
        } 
    }

Answer (score 0):

You might be going about this the wrong way. Sometimes it's easier to break a task down.

```
url = "http://a.up.w.com/i/EF8W-P67s6dqRPIj7cLlMQ!/fw/300/format/jpg/quality/90";
m = url.replace(
    /\/fw\/\d+/,"/fw/3000"
).replace(
    /\/format\/jpg/,"/format/png"
).replace(
    /\/quality\/\d+/,"/quality/100"
);
```

Comment: But what if "EF8W-P67s6dqRPIj7cLlMQ!"  is a random string?

Comment: So what? Unless it *just happens* to contain `/fw/123` in it? Which it probably won't, because I highly doubt the identifier would contain a `/` - that would cause problems for the originating source!

Answer (score 0):

May be you only need to care about this part `/300/format/jpg/quality/90`,

Then use replace like this.

```
url.replace(/(\d+)\/format\/jpg\/quality\/(\d+)/, function($0, $1, $2) { 
    return 3000 + '/format/png/quality/' + 100; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if( (m = url.match(/^(https?:\/\/a+\.up+\.w+\.com\/i\/+)([^\/]+)(\/fw\/+)([^\/]+)(\/format\/+)([^\/+]+)(\/quality\/+)([^\/]+)$/i)) ) {
    if(m[4] != "3000" || m[8] !=100) {
        document.location = m[1] + m[2] + m[3] + "3000" + m[5] + m[6] + m[7] + "100";
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone! I've got it! :P
Special thanks to @Lavi Avigdor for the inspiration (again)